# Is there any build-in inverse-function of HTF.ESCAPE_SC in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, escaping

There is a PL/SQL function [HTF.ESCAPE_SC](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/w_htf.htm#ARPLS70276) which escape special characters like `&` to `&amp;`

Example:

```
SELECT HTF.ESCAPE_SC('<parameter name="port">48677</parameter>')
FROM dual;

&lt;parameter name=&quot;port&quot;&gt;48677&lt;/parameter&gt;
```

Does anybody know the inverse function of that? Of course I could run

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    '&lt;parameter name=&quot;port&quot;&gt;48677&lt;/parameter&gt;', 
 '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>'), '&quot;','"'), '&amp;','&')
FROM dual;
```

but I wonder if there is a built-in function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the function: [DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm#i1013100)
I does encoding and decoding.

```
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT('Please encode &lt;this&gt; tag', 1) FROM dual;

Please encode <this> tag



SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT('Please decode <this> tag', 0) FROM dual;

Please decode &lt;this&gt; tag
```

Comment: No it doesn't. `SELECT dbms_xmlgen.convert('Please encode &lt;this&gt; tag') FROM dual` gives me the output `Please encode &amp;lt;this&amp;gt; tag` (Oracle 12c)

Comment: Ah. Fair enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a built in that does that. You could write a small function to prevent an unreadable stack of calls to `replace()`.

```
create or replace function unescape_sc(p_str in varchar2)
return varchar2
is
  l_str varchar2(2000) := p_str; -- adjust size as required
begin
  l_str := replace(l_str, '&amp;', '&');
  l_str := replace(l_str, '&gt;', '>');
  l_str := replace(l_str, '&lt;', '<');
  l_str := replace(l_str, '&quot;', '"');
  return l_str;
end unescape_sc;

select unescape_sc('&lt;parameter name=&quot;port&quot;&gt;48677&lt;/parameter&gt;')
from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

```
SELECT utl_i18n.unescape_reference ('&lt;parameter name=&quot;port&quot;&gt;48677&lt;/parameter&gt;')
FROM   dual
```

Output is:

```
<parameter name="port">48677</parameter>
```

Comment: It depends on your requirements. `HTF.ESCAPE_SC` escapes only `& " < >`. However, `utl_i18n.unescape_reference` unescapes many more strings (see documentation). So it is not a **inverse-function** of  `HTF.ESCAPE_SC`.